# GoogleTest EXPECT_DEATH does not catch double free()

Tags: c, googletest, free

Using the Google Test framework, I want to be able to determine that a program crashes if I accidentally free() allocated memory twice. I expected something the following to catch the crash:

```
TEST(DEATHTEST, InvalidFree)
{
    ::testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style = "threadsafe";

    int *data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    free(data);

    EXPECT_DEATH(free(data), ".*");
}
```

If I actually free() the memory twice outside of the test framework, the program crashes. However, the test case fails, reporting:

```
Death test: free(data)
    Result: failed to die.
 Error msg:
[  DEATH   ] 
[  FAILED  ] DEATHTEST.InvalidFree (3 ms)
```

I have also tried to:

```
EXPECT_EXIT(free(data), ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGABRT), ".*");
```

and I've tried with other signals like SIGSEGV.

What am I doing wrong? Is it simply not possible to catch this kind of crash? (I realize that the behavior of a double free is undefined but I'd expect that a crash should nonetheless be detectable.)

*Note: I don't actually want to test that a double free crashes. Instead, I want to verify that a function frees some allocated memory. Since I can't readily mock the free() function, instead I thought I could verify that trying to free the memory after the function has executed would indirectly test the function's memory deallocation.*

Comment: double `free()` is Undefined Behavior. It may crash, it may not, there is nothing that one can be sure when UB is invoked

Comment: In general you can't rely on double-free causing a crash. Does the test case pass if you remove EXPECT_DEATH? Maybe some memory allocator option needs to be set to increase the chance that double-free will crash

Comment: The program crashes if I free the memory twice, that is, if I execute free() outside of the EXPECT_DEATH() clause. While double free() is undefined, on this architecture and compiler combo, its behavior is a consistent crash and I would expect this to be somehow detectable by the framework.

Comment: It is generally really difficult to test memory allocation done by `malloc()`/`free` or `new`/`delete`. You don't know which framework methods call that functions or operators, too. If you use GCC, consider to use the `-wrap` option to intercept the calls. Beware of name mangling in C++, which is the language of GoogleTest.